# How do I reuse a custom function in jQuery to apply multiple css properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Super simple concept, but it's giving me trouble...

5 div elements total
1st div is centered, z-indexed to the front.
Other 4 divs are each 1/4 of the page. When hovered, each apply a unique css property to the 1st div.

[Here's what I currently have](http://codepen.io/igloude/pen/HsedJ?editors=001)

Or here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function point(a, b, c, d) {
    $(".middle").css("transition", ".15s ease-in-out all");
    $(".middle").css("border-radius", a . "% " . b . "% " . c . "% " . d . "%");
  }

  function unpoint() {
    $(".middle").css("transition", ".15s ease-in-out all");
    $(".middle").css("border-radius", "50% 50% 50% 50%");
  }

  $(".section-1")
    .on( "mouseenter", point(0, 50, 50, 50) )
    .on( "mouseleave", unpoint() );
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could make a little plugin

```
(function($) {
  function mouseenter(a, b, c, d) {
    $(".middle", this).css({
      transition: ".15s ease-in-out all",
      borderRadius: [a, b, c, d].map(function(side) { return side+"%"; }).join(" ");
    });
  }

  function mouseleave() {
    $(".middle", this).css({
      transition: ".15s ease-in-out all",
      borderRadius: "50%"
    });
  }

  $.fn.point = function(a, b, c, d) {
    return this.each(function(idx, elem)) {
      $(elem).hover(
        function() { mouseenter.call(this, a, b, c, d); },
        function() { mouseleave.call(this); }
      );
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can use it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".section-1").point(0, 50, 50, 50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my first view I found some issues with your code..

1st issue: there is syntax error in the given line. it should be + in place of .(dot)

```
$(".middle").css("border-radius", a + "% " + b + "% " + c + "% " + d + "%");
```

2nd issue: you are not assigning the function to callback but you are just calling that function. Proper syntax should be this..

```
$(".section-1")
    .on( "mouseenter", point )
    .on( "mouseleave", unpoint );
```